# Move two independent sites to network

Tags: multisite, network-admin

I have two independent sites, both have contents and plugins and themes. I know from [docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) how to convert one to a network but how do I import the second one on this network? By import I mean at DB level since I'll use directory approach for the network, any advice or help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good idea to search WP DEV before you post a new question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=migrate+multisite

And Google is a good try, too: http://www.google.com/search?&q=move+single+site+to+multisite+wordpress

The WordPress Codex is a good place to start: http://codex.wordpress.org/Migrating_Multiple_Blogs_into_WordPress_3.0_Multisite

> Since Version 3.0, WordPress includes new multisite features, meaning
>   that it can run many blogs, even with their own separate domains, on
>   one WordPress installation. This tutorial explains how to migrate
>   multiple WordPress installations into one new WordPress multisite. You
>   can migrate sites that are using their own domain, as well as sites
>   using a subdomain on your main domain.